# Relationships break when adding column using query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset with multiple tables and relationships between those tables which were auto detected when I connected to my PostgreSQL server.

But when I add a column using query, those relationships are no longer effective in the report view and all my graphs show 'blank' labels.

One thing I noticed is that in the Data view, the uuid which are used to make the relationships (my foreign keys in PSQL) appear with brackets and those brackets desappear after I add columns in query.

Before:
[image: foreign_key uuid before adding columns]

After:
[image: foreign_key uuid after adding columns]

I don't know if this helps.

I have tried adding columns with custom queries or simply duplicating an existing column.

I don't have any issue when adding columns using DAX.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't use postgres so I'm only guessing here.  When manipulating data in power query editor, it isn't rare for the machine to automatically add a 'change type' step that can affect multiple columns.  Is it possible that your shop_id has been affected by this?  Additionally, brackets are used in M (the power query language) to denote lists.  It's possible that once you modify the M code, the brackets are getting stripped out to prevent parsing issues?  (I admit i'm reaching on that one).

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the column by yourself as one of the first steps in the query editor. You can either go with the brackets or without. Make sure its the same for every other key-/foreign key.

If you lost your relationship you can edit it by yourself. After your ID´s are proparly formatted go to `Model` (the last on the left pane) and drag and drop your relationship form one table to the other. This way it should work again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I change the type of column to specify with/without brackets? Thanks